# How to change the date-format to YYYY-MM-DD in jquery?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to change date format on my website. Actually currently I am getting result like this: (Mar 17th 1:00 PM) and I want to change it like this: (2016-03-17). I searched many websites there is no conversion for this one. Please help.

My code:

```
var editStart1 = $('#modal-startdate').text();---> Getting the date (Mar 17th 1:00 PM)
$('#datepicker2').val(editStart1);---> (Trying to covert the date format to 2016-03-17)
$('#fullCalModal').modal('toggle');
$('#meeting').modal();
```

Comment: Where does the initial value come from? Would be better to use a data attribute with a properly formatted date value in it if it is dynamically generated at server. Note that a year would need to be included

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

You probably have to pull your editStart1 value into a Javascript date object.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

For example:

```
$(".selection").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
```